# how solve the boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

so my question is prove the following relation and solve the boolean expression. i'm stuck. because usually i solve the question is not like this.

i) AB+ABC+ABC=AB
ii) Z(Y+Z)(X+Y+Z)=Z

Comment: What do you mean by "solving a boolean expression"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. $LHS=AB+ABC+ABC=AB+ABC=AB(1+C)=AB.1=AB=RHS$
2. $LHS=Z(Y+Z)(X+Y+Z)=Z(Y+Z+0)(Y+Z+X)=Z(Y+Z+0.X)=Z(Y+Z)=(Z+0)(Z+Y)=Z+0.Y=Z=RHS$

This assumes that you are familiar with the various properties and identities of Boolean Algebra.

Comment: what is LHS and RHS mean?

Comment: It means "Left Hand Side" and "Right Hand Side". I used it to denote the two sides of the equality you need to prove. So getting LHS=RHS means the equality has been shown.

Comment: oh. i got it. thank you a lot. you are really helping me :)